# Add new fields to an existing InfoPath and also fill in the newly added fields

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I have an existing Infopath form in Sharepoint and they all have data in those forms. I'm able to update the new fields I add to the Infopath in SharePoint.

Now one of my problems I have is:

Those newly added fields do not contain anything. I would like to fill in those blanks by taking the existing information and stick it into those new fields.

Is it possible to do it? And how would I approach this task.

Thank you very much for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Newly added fields can have default values. These default values can be values from other existing fields using formulas. You can also set rules, putting a condition to check if the new fields are blank and then fill the data from existing fields.

Comment: Well regulated approach through this blog of yours. Awesome work.

Comment: @Deepu How do I set the rules? Is it in the InfoPath? Or I have to write code in Visual Studio... Thank you

Comment: you can set the rules in infopath form itself....you can find Rules on the ribbon. You can do with that...

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather loose in defining context as well as in used terminlogy.

But generally, if the the fields are added to an Infopath form template through Infopath Designer 2010, then the new form tempalte was created and only template with which previous forms were created can be used for editing/updating previously filled Infopath forms.

The correct solution is to put Infopath form templates into Infopath form library separately from a document library into which Infopath forms with data are stored and/or save changed form templates under different names. Otherwise, if the new changed (aka modified aka updated) Infopath form template is published into the same library where the documents or Infopath forms with data are stored, then changes to Infopath form template will overwrite the old form template and editing/changes of previous forms with data will not be possible while the old forms will be shown according to new changed form template.